# *Show* view always shows the first pin (item) in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, show

I'm working on a pinterest-like app, and I've encountered a problem recently.
When as a logged in user I try to access a pin through "show" it gives me the correct id number in the url for e.g. **http://localhost:3000/pins/7** but the description comes from the first item in the database.

Here's my Show view code:

```
<%= image_tag @pin.image.url %>

<p>
 <strong> Description: </strong>
  <%= @pin.description %>
</p>

<% if @pin.user == current_user %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(@pin) %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', pins_path %>
```

On the other hand when I try to access it via heroku through show or edit it ends with a following message:

"*We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information."*

Here is my github repo https://github.com/LeJaques/myfirstapp_new

I would be grateful for help!

Comment: Can you add your controller code which sets @pin to your question please.  Also, check in your log what is coming through in params.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue seems to be in your `set_pin` method in your `PinController`.

```
private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_pin
    @pin = Pin.find_by(params[:id])
  end
```

When passing simply `params[:id]` to `find_by`, you're going to run into issues. You should either use

```
@pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
```

or

```
@pin = Pin.find_by(id: params[:id])
```

the latter of which you oddly used in your later `correct_user` method.

Unrelated to your question, but in the future, rather than linking to your github project and having us dig through the code, please post the relevant code to your question. Doing so will help you get quicker answers in the future; this question would have been answered within five minutes (rather than in over half an hour) if your `set_pin` method had been in your question from the start.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using `find_by` to set the `@pin` incorrectly.

```
def set_pin
  @pin = Pin.find_by(params[:id])
end
```

Try to change it to just `Pin.find(params[:id])` or add a field to search by `Pin.find_by(id: params[:id])`